# Configure apache, set multiple virtualhost on EC2 AWS

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to mount an AWS server with 2 different projects. The specification of the AMI is this

> Platform: Amazon Linux (inferred)

> Details of platform: Linux/UNIX

All the AMI configuration is done, the 80 port is avaible. The IP is this http://13.59.121.162/

I'm using apache to serve the files.

I tried to find the folder /etc/apache2/sites-available but this distribution has not that directory. I have not idea how to create it manually and the inside files. I found this file

```
/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

And I edited and added a new VirtualHost lines

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin foo@bar.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/food
  ServerName 13.59.121.162/food
  ErrorLog logs/food-error_log
  CustomLog logs/food-access_log common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin foo@bar.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/backoffice
  ServerName 13.59.121.162/admin
  ErrorLog logs/admin-food-error_log
  CustomLog logs/admin-food-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

The apache's directory structure is this

```
/var
  /www
   /html
     /backoffice
      -index.html <-- <h1>Aquí backoffice</h1>
     /food
      -index.html <-- <h1>Aquí la comida</h1>
```

I visited `http://13.59.121.162/food` but I have an error `(ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT) Can't access to this website.` I hope to see Aquí la comida, but nothing. I have the same error with the other configuration, but if I visit `http://13.59.121.162` it shows Aquí la comida

What did I do wrong?

Comment: For me `http://13.59.121.162/food` shows 404 Not Found error page

Answer (score 0):

nowhere in your configuration have you granted access, you need to grant access to the directories,, something like this...

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    <Directory /var/www/html/food>
       Require All Granted
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```